# prosessing a link string in php

Tags: php, hyperlink, str-replace, explode

I have a html file which containes some links. The source code here is typically src="read.php?file=http://www.something.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ccc.html&&someotherstring"

aaa, bbb and ccc being the only that varies, all the links are simular in structure.

I need to make this look like src="http://www.something.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/mobile.html"

I can get rid of the "read.php?file=" with str_replace, but if I try for instance explode with "/", I explode all the other "/" occurring in the html file.

Anyone got some good tips?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$body="src=\"read.php?file=www.something.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ccc.html&&someotherstring\"";

$p1=strpos($body,"read.php?file=");
$p2=strpos($body,"\"",$p1+5);
$p3=strpos($body,"&",$p1+5);
$p4=strrpos($body,"/",$p3);
$replace_str1=substr($body,$p1,$p2-$p1);
$replace_str2=substr($body,$p1+14,$p4-$p1-21)."mobile.html";
echo str_replace($body,$replace_str1,$replace_str2);

?>
```

may be you can try this.

Comment: The point is that I have a lot of links in the page etc, but it is only the ones starting with read.php?file=http://www.something.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ccc.html&&someotherstring I want to edit

Comment: @user3517166 you can try my edited answer. Hopfully useful for you.